# Log in website using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to log me in a website with requests, but all I have try don't work :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
s = requests.session()
url = 'https://www.ent-place.fr/CookieAuth.dll?GetLogon?curl=Z2F&reason=0&formdir=5'


def authenticate():
    headers = {'username': 'myuser', 'password': 'mypasss', '_Id': 'submit'}
    page = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(page.content)
    value = soup.form.find_all('input')[2]['value']
    headers.update({'value_name':value})
    auth = s.post(url, params=headers, cookies=page.cookies)

authenticate()
```

or :

```
import requests

payload = {
    'inUserName': 'user',
    'inUserPass': 'pass'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.ent-place.fr/CookieAuth.dll?GetLogon?curl=Z2F&reason=0&formdir=5', data=payload)
    print(p.text)
    print(p.status_code)
    r = s.get('A protected web page url')
    print(r.text)
```

When I try this with the .status_code, it return 200 but I want 401 or 403 for do a script like 'if login'...

I have found this but I think it works in python 2, but I use python 3 and I don't know how to convert... :

```
import requests
import sys

payload = {
    'username': 'sopier',
    'password': 'somepassword'
}

with requests.Session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr}) as c:
    c.post('http://m.kaskus.co.id/user/login', data=payload)
    r = c.get('http://m.kaskus.co/id/myform')
    print 'sopier' in r.content
```

Somebody know how to do ?